# Error updating Android SDK (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, circleci

I'm trying to update the sdk via the command line using this command

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-23.0.2
```

and I'm getting this error

```
 echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-23.0.2
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
  Validate XML
  Parse XML
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  XML verification failed for https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml.
Line 306:41, Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 306; columnNumber: 41; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '11b' is not a valid value for 'integer'.
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  XML verification failed for https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml.
Line 306:41, Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 306; columnNumber: 41; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '11b' is not a valid value for 'integer'.
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-23.0.2'
Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
```

The problem is probably here

```
Line 306:41, Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 306; columnNumber: 41; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '11b' is not a valid value for 'integer'.
```

This is running on a CircleCI box, and it has been running fine for a few days until now.

Anyone has an idea of whats happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML in question was versioned 11.  The latest appears to be 12, and our builds are back on track as well.  For a moment, the Android team appears to have fooled us.

Try rebuilding, but also note that some DNS etc could result in you not getting your update right away.

Comment: Yeap, back to normal here too